# Use a Firestore Database in Dialogflow project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I want to integrate my Firestore using data I got in my Dialogflow project.

I was searching in the net and I found just some random things.
I wrote some console.log inside, because I want to understand how does it work, but nothing seems happening, and I don't even know where I can find my logs.

Here it is my index.js Dialogflow code:

```
'use strict';

// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
//const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const {dialogflow,Permission,SimpleResponse,Image,Carousel,BrowseCarousel,BasicCard,Button,BrowseCarouselItem,Suggestions,List,MediaObject} = require('actions-on-google');
// Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log('Request headers: ');
});
```

Is there something I am missing?
Sorry, but it's my first time using Dialogflow.

Comment: For starters you're missing a description of the problem you're having. {: We're happy to help... but we're not sure what the problem is. If you can update your question to indicate your problem, or what errors you're getting, or what is or isn't working, we might be able to give you more info.

Comment: It's my first time using DialogFlow fullfillment, and it just seems nothing happening! The log is not working!

Comment: Typically updating your question, and saying in a comment that you've done so, is the best approach - that way it is clear to us what the problem is without reading lots of comments. It looks like your log statement isn't showing anything besides a static string. Can you also update the question to include screen shots of the Intents screens in Dialogflow? And can you confirm how you are deploying your webhook and possibly show a screen shot of the Fulfillment tab in Dialogflow?

Comment: @Prisoner edited. I pasted a part of the code that is not using Dialogflow intents. I want to check my console.log inside the export.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment. 
Don't know where the tab is, maybe it will help...

Comment: How are you deploying your webhook? Are you using the built-in editor, or are you writing it using Firebase Cloud Functions and deploying it to Firebase?

Comment: @Prisoner built-in editor of Dialogflow project fulfillment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the built-in editor, your logs will be in the Firebase Cloud Functions logs section. To get there

1. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/ and select your project.
2. Select "Functions" on the left navigation.
3. Select "Logs" in the navigation towards the top.

[image]